Coherent States with Large Photon Number $\rightarrow a^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle = \alpha^*|\alpha \rangle$
In my quantum optics studies, this property is often taken for granted: Large Photon Number $\rightarrow a^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle = \alpha^*|\alpha \rangle$ (this assumption is used in experiments like homodyne detection etc... where one of the fields is strong).
However, I am not exactly sure where this comes from mathematically. See below:
$$a^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle = e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} a^{\dagger} |n\rangle $$
$$= e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} \sqrt{n+1} |n+1\rangle$$
$$\approx e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} \sqrt{n} |n+1\rangle$$
$$= e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} \sqrt{n+1} |n+1\rangle$$
$$\approx e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^{n-2} \alpha \alpha^*}{\sqrt{(n-1)!}} |n+1\rangle$$
$$\approx e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}  \alpha^*\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\sqrt{(n-1)!}} |n+1\rangle \hspace{1cm} m =n-1$$
$$\approx e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}  \alpha^*\sum_{m=-1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^{m}}{\sqrt{m!}} |m+2\rangle \hspace{1cm} $$
I seem to be missing something critical here, because I can not arrive at this conclusion ...

Sorry but this is clearly a “check-my-work” question, and thus out of scope.  This is not a homework help site.  If your question is not homework, please transform it to highlight the concept you are not understanding.  Maybe continue by indicating where did you get this equation from and what sources have you consulted?

Consider to change the equation in the title to an approximation (the creation operator does not have any eigenstates).

Here is a neat trick:
$$a^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle = e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} a^{\dagger} |n\rangle $$
$$= e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} \sqrt{n+1} |n+1\rangle$$
$$=e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}} (n+1)|n+1\rangle$$
$$=e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\frac{d}{d\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^{n+1}}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}|n+1\rangle $$
$$=e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left(e^{|\alpha|^2/2}|\alpha\rangle-|0\rangle\right)$$
$$=\alpha^*|\alpha\rangle +\frac{d}{d\alpha}|\alpha\rangle$$
I am not sure why exactly the derivative term could be neglected for strong field $|\alpha|\gg 1$.
I don't think you can obtain $\alpha^*$ without using the exponent in some way (I do it via the derivative). In the question you represent $\alpha^2$ as $\alpha\alpha^*$ but this is wrong since in the series for coherent state one has $\alpha$ not $|\alpha|$.

There is exact equality
$$
a|\alpha\rangle = \alpha |\alpha\rangle.
$$
Thus, $|\alpha\rangle\equiv |\tilde{0}\rangle$ can be considered as a vacuum vector for the new operators
$$
b = a - \alpha,\quad b^\dagger = a^\dagger - \alpha^*,\quad [b,b^\dagger] = 1.
$$
In the case when $|\alpha| \gg 1$, for vectors
$$
|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{n\geq 0} \psi_n (b^\dagger)^n|\tilde{0}\rangle\quad\mbox{where}\ n,\psi_n\sim 1 = |\alpha|^0,
$$
that can be said to be sufficiently close to the vector $|\tilde{0}\rangle$, the following approximate equalities are true:
$$
(a^\dagger)^l a^m |\Psi\rangle \approx (\alpha^*)^l\alpha^m |\Psi\rangle,\quad \mbox{for}\ l,m\sim 1
$$
These approximate equalities give a formal reason to say that $a\approx\alpha$, $a^\dagger\approx \alpha^*$ near the coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$. The corrections are formally small since they contain smaller powers of $\alpha$, $\alpha^*$.
